# xamarin.forms - hide components on rotation

Tags: xamarin.forms, orientation

In Xamarin.Forms, when the phone is rotated I want to hide certain XAML components.   I can't seem to find anything available from xamarin simple to use... can someone point me in the right direction?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a Xamarin.Forms `Page`, you could subscribe to the `SizeChanged` event or override the `OnSizeAllocated` method.  There is some good [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/device-orientation?tabs=vswin#reacting-to-changes-in-orientation) that describes both options.  Below is an example of using `OnSizeAllocated`:

```cs
private double width = 0;
private double height = 0;

protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height); //must be called

    if (this.width != width || this.height != height)
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        if (this.width > this.height) 
        {
            // reconfigure for landscape
        }
        else
        {
            // reconfigure for portrait
        }
    }
}
```